# homepage not fully loading after loutout

Tags: homepage

My homepage is working fine when I am logged in to my wordpress.But the moment I logout and check the homepage then it not loads fully.
Please help you can check my site guudeal.com

Thanks,
techars

Comment: Your site has two 404 errors likely caused by the Autooptimize plugin that it can't find the css stylesheet. Clear the cache, disable the plugin and reactivate it to see if it is works.

Comment: Thanks for reply..But I have tried your solution but same the unloaded homepage shows every time. Even I have deleted Auto optimize plugin...but still

Comment: Well, check your template html, your site is still referring to this for your stylesheet `<link type="text/css" media="all" href="https://guudeal.com/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_4fd56eb0a62f03ebab9bde6583b02bbb.css" rel="stylesheet">`, which is a cache version and probably no longer exist. Normal wordpress site would refer the style at `<link type="text/css" media="all" href="https://guudeal.com/wp-content/themes/your_theme/style.css" rel="stylesheet">